# Problems with layers in Cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, layer

Yo,
I'm having a problem in coco2d to do with layers. I have a background, using this code:

```
CCSprite * background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background_menu.png"];
    [self addChild:background];
    background.position = ccp(240,160);
```

It is basically just a sprite, with a position that I have assigned to it. Then, I have a menu, made using CCMenu, with four CCMenuItemImage. When I run the program, the background blocks out the menu, so all I can see is the background. I was wondering how to make it so that the menu appears on top of the background. I know this has something to do with layers, but I am a bit confused about how to make layers and how to create a hierarchy with them, so that some appear on top of others.

Comment: what is the position of the menu ? it may just be 'off screen', not behind the background.  When you add children to a layer, without specifying a zorder, the last one (in your the menu) should be above the first one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the z order. Try:

```
[self addChild:background z:-1];
```

or add the menu with a higher z order

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the z order, which is the first thing to try, also try commenting out the background's `addChild` method so only the menu is getting added as a child. This is to verify that the menu itself is properly being added and positioned. If it is, then add the background back, but make sure to change the z order, OR put the menu's `addChild` method AFTER the background's `addChild` method so it is automatically added on top of the background if you don't want to mess with the z order.